# Python 2.7 - Progress Bar without External Library

Tags: python, python-2.7, progress-bar, normalize

I have a python function which extracts images from some sensor data file. The function loops over the images and extract them sequentialy.

There are around 25000 images within sensor data file. The number is not fixed. However I have a variable which dynamically stores the number of messages/images.

I want to design a progress bar by not using any external library. The progress bar print percentage completed with a '#' character similar to:

> Progress 53%: #########################

How I can normalize the number of images between 1-100%?

Comment: Simply dividing the file count by 100 is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a great way of doing the percentage while having it work inside of IDLE (because idle doesn't support any clearing or `\b`).

So, instead, I simply made it a visual progress bar:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time

class Progress():
    def __init__(self, total_images):
        self.total_images = total_images
        self.bar_width = 5
        self.previous = 0
        self.prompt = "Progress: "
        print(self.prompt, end='')

    def update(self, image_number):
        percentage = float(image_number) / self.total_images
        number_of_ticks = percentage * self.bar_width
        delta = int(number_of_ticks - self.previous)
        self.previous = int(number_of_ticks)
        if delta > 0:
            print("#" * delta, end='')

total_images = 10
progress_bar = Progress(total_images)
for current_image in range(1, total_images+1):
    progress_bar.update(current_image)
    time.sleep(.1)
```

**Output**:

```
Progress: #####
```

If you want a longer bar, you can modify the `self.bar_width` property.  Optionally, you could add all of these as argument, but I was unsure as to which ones you'd find useful.

Comment: I will modify it according to my scenario.